# How to get an image from a website using QtWebKit?

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qtwebkit

For example if the page is http://qt-project.org/ and I need to get http://qt-project.org/images/qtdn/developer-guides-illustration.png, but I only have the name of the image
(developer-guides-illustration.png)?

Comment: you mean that you have a page + an image name OR you have a domain + a partial URL for the file ?

Comment: i have the page (http://qt-project.org/ ) + image name (developer-guides-illustration.png)